# confusing intermittent failure with pycrypto

Tags: pycrypto

I've been playing with python's crypto library, and I built a simple threading server to encrypt and decrypt.  The problem I'm having is that about 1 out of 3 decryptions comes back incorrectly.  Here's the code:

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        global KEY
        request_text = ''
        while request_text.rfind("\n") == -1:
            sock_data='';
            recv_size=8192
            sock_data=self.request.recv(recv_size)
            if sock_data == '':
                print "hangup"
                break
            request_text = request_text + sock_data

        args = json.loads(request_text)
        print request_text
        print "\n"
        if args['command'] == 'encrypt':
            iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
            cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
            crypted_message = iv + b'|' + cipher.encrypt(unquote_plus(args['message']))
            response = {'encrypted_message': binascii.hexlify(crypted_message)}

        if args['command'] == 'decrypt':
            unhexed = binascii.unhexlify(args['message'])
            components = unhexed.split('|')
            iv = components[0]
            cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
            decrypted_message = cipher.decrypt(components[1])
            response = {'decrypted_message': decrypted_message}

        self.request.sendall(json.dumps(response) + "\n")
```

Often, I get this error from python:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "cryptoserver.py", line 40, in handle
    cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.4-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 95, in new
    return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.4-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 59, in __init__
    blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.4-x86_64/egg/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long
----------------------------------------
```

but just as often, I get no error, but the decryption doesn't work correctly.  I'm using this php to test it:

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");

function encrypt($text) {
    $package = array("command" => "encrypt",
                    "message" => base64_encode($text));
    $package_json = json_encode($package);
    $serverSays = transmit($package_json);
    $serverSaysArray = json_decode($serverSays);
    return $serverSaysArray->encrypted_message;
}

function decrypt($text) {
    $package = array("command" => "decrypt",
                    "message" => $text);

    $package_json = json_encode($package);
    $serverSays = transmit($package_json);
    $serverSaysArray = json_decode($serverSays);
    return base64_decode($serverSaysArray->decrypted_message);
}

function transmit($package) {
    global $CRYPTO_PORT;
    global $CRYPTO_HOST;

    $serverLink = fsockopen($CRYPTO_HOST, $CRYPTO_PORT);
    if ($serverLink === FALSE) {
        error_log("Could not connect to encryption server");
        return FALSE;
    }
    fwrite($serverLink, $package . "\n");

    $response = '';
    while (!feof($serverLink)) {
        $response .= fgets($serverLink, 128);
    }
    fclose($serverLink);
    return $response;
}

while (TRUE) {
    $enc = encrypt('totsadaddywoopxxx');
    print "$enc\n";
    $dec = decrypt($enc);
    print "$dec\n";
    $enc = encrypt('totsadaddywoopxxx');
    print "$enc\n";
    $dec = decrypt($enc);
    print "$dec\n";
    $enc = encrypt('totsadaddywoopxxx');
    print "$enc\n";
    $dec = decrypt($enc);
    print "$dec\n";
    #print decrypt('1c6dee677126551fa4b3f0732986dc3b7c985c64c07075e3651213d7a69435bcd87083e729e8de860c');
    #print "\n";
    #print decrypt('550cbec7498371dc01bcd6b88fc623b47cb2efd1881da6e07ee992229308305992bbc7ccc374f00c91d56d10a68d6110e2');
    print "===========================\n";

    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your decryption routine you use:

```
 unhexed.split('|')
```

to find the boundary between IV and the ciphertext. However, the IV is generated randomly by the sender. Sometimes, one of its 16 bytes will be 124, that is the boundary character '|'.

When that happens (in roughly 6% of the cases), the decryption routine will initialize the cipher either with

- an IV with length between 1 and 15 bytes, which leads to the exception, or
- an IV with length 0, which leads to the incorrect decryption, because in PyCrypto versions<2.6 an all-zero 16 byte IV will be used by default

In the decryption routine you should have instead:

```
components = [ unhexed[:AES.block_size], unhexed[AES.block_size+1:] ]
```

Or you could get rid of the '|' separator altogether.

Comment: thanks.  I thought it was something like that, but I'm a newbie to this stuff and this is a cut and paste from the example on pycrypto.  Awesome!

Comment: @ernst-schoen-rene welcome! If you are happy with the answer, would you please accept it?